# Get list arguments/flag cmake

Tags: cmake

I want write `cmake ... -variable=value`.

I want use this variable in code.

example:

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt -TEST_MESSAGE=Hello
```

and

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6) 

set (PROJECT hello_world) 

project (${PROJECT}) 

message (${TEST_MESSAGE})
```

How to?

Comment: try changing the `-TEST_MESSAGE=Hello` to `-DTEST_MESSAGE=Hello`...

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know this method. i want without using -D. This is real?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to use command line options without `-D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Create a wrapper (batch, bash script, Python script or whatever) called "cmake" to parse arguments and inside the wrapper call

```
cmake ... -Dvariable=value
```

B) Or get [source](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html) of CMAKE, modify parsing of command line arguments code, recompile it yourself and use.

**But** I would strongly suggest to just use `-D` option as everyone else